# How to load view from alternative directory in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, namespaces

In my Laravel 4 application's root directory, I have a folder **`themes`**. Inside the **`themes`** folder, I have **`default`** and **`azure`**.
How can I access view from this **`themes/default`** folder in a specific route.

```
Route::get('{slug}', function($slug) {
    // make view from themes/default here
});
```

### My directory structure:

*-app*

*--themes*

*---default*

*---azure*

I need to load views from `localhost/laravel/app/themes/default` folder. Please explain this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here I am not accessing my project from **`public`** folder. Instead of this I am accessing from project root itself.

I have seen a forum discussion about **`Using alternative path for views`** [here](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=8277). But I am little confused about this.The discussed solution was,

You'd add a **`location`** like,

```
View::addLocation('/path/to/your/views');
```

Then add **`namespace`** for theme,

```
View::addNamespace('theme', '/path/to/themes/views');
```

Then render it,

```
return View::make('theme::view.name');
```

What will be the value for `/path/to/` ?

Can I use the same project in different operating system without changing the path?

Yes, we can do this using the following,

Put the following in `app/start/global.php`

```
    View::addLocation(app('path').'/themes/default');
    View::addNamespace('theme', app('path').'/themes/default');
```

Then call view like the default way,

```
    return View::make('page');
```

This will render `page.php` or `page.blade.php` file from `project_directory/app/themes/defualt` folder.

Comment: I appreciate this post, it has a lot of helpful information on it! Can you explain where the View::addLocation() and View::addNamespace() are supposed to go? Am I to assume that this requires creating a ServiceProvider?

Comment: Is there a reason why this wouldn't work in a Route filter? I tried it there and it is not working there, but does in global.php.

Comment: @pthurmond why would you want to put it in a route filter?

Comment: This is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27458439/how-to-set-view-file-path-in-laravel with perfect description

Answer (score 37):

This is entirely possible with Laravel 4. What you're after is actually the view environment. 
You can register namespace hints or just extra locations that the finder will cascade too. Take a look [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/View/Environment.php#L488)

You'd add a location like so:

```
View::addLocation('/path/to/your/views');
```

It might be easier if you namespace them though, just in case you have conflicting file names as your path is appended to the array so it will only cascade so far until it finds an appropriate match. Namespaced views are loaded with the double colon syntax.

```
View::addNamespace('theme', '/path/to/themes/views');

return View::make('theme::view.name');
```

You can also give addNamespace an array of view paths instead of a single path.

Comment: Deleted my answer, this is indeed the proper way.

Comment: @Chirag Can you explain this with my view location `(themes/default)` and route?

Comment: I have already seen this http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=8277 But I am not clear, that's why asked here.

Comment: You have to add theme with code `View::addNamespace('theme', '/path/to/themes/default');`
then use it with code `return View::make('theme::view.name');`

Comment: @lucip Please check my updated question and give me detailed explanation instead of `/path/to/`.

Comment: That means your path is : app('path').'/../themes/default'

Comment: Hi. Will this override views or just use the latest added path instead? That would be great if it override only those files that are in new template file :)

Comment: Cant believe this isnt in Laravel.com's /doc... wow. Thanks for sharing that.

Answer (score 2):

I've developed a theme package for laravel 5 with features like:

- Views & Asset seperation in theme folders
- Theme inheritence: Extend any theme and create Theme hierarcies

Try it here: [igaster/laravel-theme](https://github.com/igaster/laravel-theme)

Answer (score 0):

`\View::addLocation($directory);` works fine but the new right way to do it  is using `loadViewsFrom($path, $namespace)` (available on any service provider).