# Where in Laravel 4 to declare new location and new namespace

Tags: php, view, laravel

I am trying to create an alternative view and found this answer:

[How to load view from alternative directory in Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954758/how-to-load-view-from-alternative-directory-in-laravel-4I)

which suggested using this code

```
View::addLocation(app('path').'/themes/default');
View::addNamespace('theme', app('path').'/themes/default');
```

But cannot decide where to declare these statements . In which file can I use this code?

start.php,path.php,app.php,global.php or in another file .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using the [app/config/view.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/config/view.php#L16) configuration file to add view loading locations (via the `paths` array) is not enough for your needs, you can probably fit that into a service provider.

Laravel actually uses the View Library's [Service Provider](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/View/ViewServiceProvider.php) to register the view paths locations (based on the `app/config/view.php` config file as mentioned).

One thing you can do is add your own service provider class and add in your view logic there, in order to add a location / namespaces as you need. (You can even have your service provider read your own configuration files in order to determine locations/namespaces).

If you need help creating a service provider/don't know where to put one, read [this on creating a Laravel application library](http://fideloper.com/laravel-4-application-setup-app-library-autoloading).

Comment: could it be more simple than this ?   when the View class is ready 'Loaded' ?

Comment: It can be more simpler than that! Pop it in one of the `start.php`/`global.php` files you listed - the code can go there just as easily! For "best practices", I think you'll find a general preference around creating an application library - it's more maintainable in the long run. However, to each their own - you may not need it for any "long term" project. I certainly write plenty of "short-term" apps which don't use a more complicated code structure.

Answer (score 1):

If that's all you'll be doing, putting it inside `app/start/global.php` works just fine. There's really no need for a new service provider for such a simple task.

However, if after some time you realize your `global.php` file is starting to get too heavy and messy, then you should go for a service provider, as @fideloper mentioned.