# How to set view file path in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a directory structure for laravel app like this:

```
app/
   admin/
      controllers/
      views/ -> for admin views
   ...
   views/ -> for frontend views
```

How can I set the view path for controllers in admin? I don't want to use `View::addLocation` or `View::addNamespace` because I might have the same view file name for admin and frontend, and don't want to add a namespace for every `View::make('namespace::view.file')`.

I see in http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/View/View.html there is a `setPath` method, but how do I call it? `View::setPath` raised undefined method error.

Comment: maybe try some symlinks if thats what you mean, dunno what the exact goal is

Comment: my goal is to separate views for admin and for frontend.

Comment: Then just make "admin" folder in the standard views directory, no? Then you reference the views like admin/mystuff

Comment: I want to have a separate admin directory for controllers, views, etc. It's cleaner I think than having admin sub directory in each controllers and views.

Comment: Well of you like it complicated...

Comment: not really, and it looks lots better for directory structure, now I just need to tell laravel to find the views in specific directory.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have two ways to accomplish your goal. First, let's have a look at `app/config/view.php`. That's where the path(s) for view loading are defined.

This is the default:

```
'paths' => array(__DIR__.'/../views'),
```

### Method 1: Load both directories

You can easily add the admin directory to the array

```
'paths' => array(
    __DIR__.'/../views',
    __DIR__.'/../admin/views
),
```

Now the big disadvantage of this: view names have to be unique. Otherwise the view in the path specified first will be taken.
Since you don't want to use a view namespace I suppose you don't want a syntax like `admin.viewname` either. You'll probably like method 2 more ;)

### Method 2: Change the view page at runtime

<s>Every Laravel config can be changed at runtime using the `Config::set` method.</s>

```
Config::set('view.paths', array(__DIR__.'/../admin/views'));
```

Apparently setting the config won't change anything because it is loaded when the application bootstraps and ignored afterwards.

To change the path at runtime you have to create a new instance of the `FileViewFinder`.
Here's how that looks like:

```
$finder = new \Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder(app()['files'], array(app_path().'/admin/views'));
View::setFinder($finder);
```

### Method 3: Use addLocation but without default path

You could also remove the default path in `app/config/view.php`

```
'paths' => array(),
```

And then use `View::addLocation` in any case (frontend and admin)

```
View::addLocation(app_path().'/views');
View::addLocation(app_path().'/admin/views');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I think method 1 is the same as `View::addLocation`.
I tried method 2 but it doesn't seem to work, I put `Config::set` in the controller `__construct`, but laravel seems to ignore that (means laravel still load the view file from 'original' path).

Comment: Sorry... that happens when you don't test the things you post on SO. Take a look at the updated answer. This time I even tested it ;)

Comment: Right now I'm going to use method 3, but I think I'll consider to use method 2 later, because method 3 might raise another problem when I have another view directory (although it's less possible) in one module (frontend/admin), anyway method 2 looks more 'right way' to do this IMHO :)

Answer (score 6):

In the latest version 6 i am doing it this ways:

```
View::getFinder()
     ->setPaths([
           base_path('themes/frontend/views'), 
           base_path('themes/admin/views')]
     )
```

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 5.5, other solutions did not work. In boot method of a service provider

```
View::getFinder()->prependLocation(
 resource_path('views') . '/theme'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

try it like this

```php
View::addNamespace('admin', app_path() . '/admin/views');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function() {
  Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('admin::index');
  });
});
```