# load the view from theme folder

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

Hey i am working on laravel for the first time so my problem is this that I am using 2 packages ie

**"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.4.*"**
**"teepluss/theme": "dev-master",**

dompdf is to make a dynamic page into pdf and as I am using teepluss theme so all my view is in the themes folder

**this is my controller method**

```
public function previewform(){
    if(Auth::check())   {
         $pdf = App::make('dompdf');
         $pdf->loadView(('user.previewform'));
         return $pdf->stream();
    }else {
          return \Redirect::route('home');
    }
}
```

So when I am using $pdf->loadView('user.previewform') , it gives me a error because it will load the view from app/view folder . so how can change loadview directory so that I can see view from theme directory

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load view from alternative directory in Laravel 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954758/how-to-load-view-from-alternative-directory-in-laravel-4)

Answer (score 1):

Kindly read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954758/how-to-load-view-from-alternative-directory-in-laravel-4). All you need is to set `view` environment.

1. Add location for new directory
2. Assign namespace
3. Use it with namespace

I have not added detail as this question is already answered.