# laravel 4 weird template syntax

Tags: php, syntax, laravel-4

I have this line in the code which I think is causing a 500 error:

```
View::make('theme::emails.enquiry_form', ['data' => Input::all()])->render()
```

I am fairly familiar with `View::make`, but I have not seen `theme::emails.enquiry_form` before.

There is a dir structure which includes the template the line is referring to (`src/public/themes/<site_name>/templates/emails/`).

I have had a look around but I can't find a reference to this - even knowing what this kind of reference is called would be a help.

Comment: See the first answer here, might shed some light on it for you.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954758/how-to-load-view-from-alternative-directory-in-laravel-4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load view from alternative directory in Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954758/how-to-load-view-from-alternative-directory-in-laravel-4)

Comment: yes perfect, thanks very much